# How can I make my React app only render when an expensive calculation is finished?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Beginner here, I'm afraid I'm getting in a complete muddle.

Doing a memory game exercise where I'd like a 3x3 grid of images randomly selected from a folder of (say) 40, with a new random set of 9 images rendering when clicking an image updates the `clickCount` in the game state (the goal being to click as many unclicked images as possible). Perhaps the problem is my slow ThinkPad, but the function which returns the array of objects with urls takes so long that the app can crash (random array not ready) or randomly skip image on-load function calls (want to fix this before I add scoreboard logic, missing below).

I'm literally just beginning with React, so I've been combing through `suspense`, `memo`, lazy loading, promises/async etc. but I'm struggling to understand enough at this early stage in my learning to know which one is right for this situation.

imageLoader.js

```
// Import all images (Webpack)
const importAll = (r) => {
  let images = [];
  r.keys().forEach((item, i) => {
    images.push({
      ...r(item),
      id: `img${i}`,
      clickCount: 0,
    });
  });
  return images;
};
const imageExport = importAll(require.context("./images", false, /\.jpg$/));

export { imageExport };
```

Game.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import ImageElement from "./ImageElement";
import { imageExport } from "../imageLoader";
import "../styles/Game.css";

// SET GRID SIZE (no. of tiles per length of square)
const gridSize = 3;

const Game = () => {
  const [gameState, setGameState] = useState(imageExport);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(0);
  const [tileSet, setTileSet] = useState(null);
  const gridCount = gridSize ** 2;

  // function to return random tile array
  const randomiseTiles = useCallback(
    (gridCount) => {
      const imgQuantity = Object.keys(gameState).length;
      const getRandomIndex = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * imgQuantity);
      let imgIndexes = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < gridCount; i++) {
        const newRandomIndex = getRandomIndex();
        if (imgIndexes.some((index) => index === newRandomIndex)) {
          // is duplicate, try again
          i--;
        } else {
          imgIndexes.push(newRandomIndex);
        }
      }

      // FIX: successive high IDs crash the app as the array isn't ready in time
      const imgSet = imgIndexes.map((id) => gameState[id]);

      if (!imgSet.some((img) => img.clickCount !== 0)) {
         // add logic later to guarantee at least one img is always unclicked
      }
      return imgSet;
    },
    [gameState]
  );

  // setTileSet after initial render to keep useState immutable
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!tileSet) {
      setTileSet(randomiseTiles(gridCount));
    }
  }, []);

  // report loading
  const reportLoaded = () => {
    setIsLoaded((prevIsLoaded) => {
      if (prevIsLoaded < gridCount) {
        return prevIsLoaded + 1;
      };
      // FIX: Is there a better way to reset isLoaded?
      return 1;
    });
  };

  // generate new tile set on image click
  useEffect(() => {
    setTileSet(randomiseTiles(gridCount));
  }, [gameState, randomiseTiles, gridCount]);

  // update game state on click
  const updateGameState = (id) => {
    const index = Number(id);
    setGameState((prevGameState) => {
      const newGameState = [...prevGameState];
      newGameState[index] = {
        ...prevGameState[index],
        clickCount: prevGameState[index].clickCount + 1,
      };
      return newGameState;
    });
  };

  const gameStyle = isLoaded === gridCount ? {
    display: "grid",
    gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${gridSize}, 1fr)`,
    gridTemplateRows: `repeat(${gridSize}, 1fr)`,
  } : {
    display: "none"
  };

  return !tileSet ? null : (
    <>
      {isLoaded < gridCount && <div>Replace with loader animation etc.</div>}
      <div id="game" style={gameStyle}>
        {/* FIX: Sometimes renders before tileSet is ready /*}
        {tileSet.map((img) => {
          return (
            <ImageElement
              key={img.id}
              src={img.default}
              imgId={img.id}
              reportLoaded={reportLoaded}
              reportClick={updateGameState}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Game;
```

ImageElement.js

```
import React from "react";

// pure component
export default const ImageElement = ({ src, reportLoaded, reportClick, imgId }) => {
  return (
    <img
      key={`image-${imgId}`}
      src={src}
      alt="image-alt-text"
      {/* I randomly get between 5-9 triggers of reportLoaded on each click
          even when all images load on the screen correctly
      */}
      onLoad={reportLoaded}
      onClick={() => reportClick(imgId)};
    />
  );
};
```

Ask me any questions you want if I've been unclear, I'm just completely stuck at this point and would appreciate some input (on the outlined problem or anything else I've done wrong).

Thank you!

Comment: Can you place the code in codesandbox where we can debug and troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing some things that are inefficient. `array.some()` looks at the array 1 element at a time until it finds a match or hits the end of the array. That's fine to do once, but you are doing it `gridCount` times, which starts to add up. Instead of `array.some()`, you can make an object to keep track of which indexes have been used:

```
let usedIndexes = {};
for (let i = 0; i < gridCount; i++) {
    const newRandomIndex = getRandomIndex();

    
    //if (imgIndexes.some((index) => index === newRandomIndex)) { //this is slow

    if (usedIndexes[newRandomIndex] === true) { //this is really fast
      // is duplicate, try again
      i--;
    } else {
      imgIndexes.push(newRandomIndex);

      usedIndexes[newRandomIndex] = true;
    }
  }
```

Another inefficient thing you are doing is that you are choosing more random indexes than you actually need, because you are allowing it to pick indexes that are already used and then throwing them away. Here is how you can only pick the number of indexes that you need:

```
//prefill imgChoices with all the unused indexes:
let imgChoices = [];
for(let i = 0; i < imgQuantity; i++) {
    imgChoices.push(i);
}

//not going to use this anymore:
//const getRandomIndex = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * imgQuantity);

for(let j = 0; j < gridCount; j++) {
    //imgChoices.length will decrease by 1 each iteration as indexes are used up:
    const newRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgChoices.length);

    //imgChoices only contains unused indexes, so we can take an index from
    // it and we don't have to check if it's used:
    const newRandomIndex = imgChoices[newRandomNumber];
    imgIndexes.push(newRandomIndex);


    if(newRandomNumber < imgChoices.length - 1) {
        //if we didn't pick the last element, replace the index we chose
        // with the one at the end and eliminate the end element:
        imgChoices[newRandomNumber] = imgChoices.pop();
    }
    else {
        //if we picked the last element, just eliminate it:
        imgChoices.pop();
    }
}
```

The code above is all that you need to pick indexes. See what happens to the performance.

Comment: Thanks for this! Yes, your version is much more efficient, the site is noticeably more responsive and I learned something very useful (sorry I can't upvote your answer, I'm too new). I'm still getting that `onLoad` function fired a random amount of times, but at this point it's responsive enough that I'm almost inclined to leave out the loader (the images all load fine, they just don't all report each render). Might you have any further thoughts?

Comment: I don't have the ability to run it, so it's hard to figure out exactly what's going on.

Comment: One change that I'd suggest is not to use a count variable to keep track of the images loading. I would instead use an object where the keys are IDs unique to the images & set the value to true as the load events come in (just like `usedIndexes` in part 1 of my answer). If you `console.log` that, you'll a better idea of what's happening.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I didn't upload a working version because the images aren't mine, I downloaded them and are using them purely for practice and was unsure of the copyright of 'distributing' them, but equally putting a version with different images seemed pointless since part of the problem was the loading time of those specific images. I'll log the used indexes as suggested and take it from there. Thanks for your time!